# Can someone help me understand why I need an IF and WHILE for this answer?

Tags: java

Quick question- I have found the correct answer to this quiz question but I don't fully understand it.

**here is the question-**

Given a Scanner reference variable named input that has been associated with an input source consisting of a sequence of lines, write the code necessary to read in every line and print them all out on a single line, separated by a space.

**here is the answer-**

```
if(input.hasNext())
    System.out.print(input.nextLine());
    while (input.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(" " + input.nextLine());
    }
}
```

**My question is**, why does there need to be an if and while statement. I understand I need to first read in the line and then print it out. Why wouldn't it be sufficient to have just :

```
while(input.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(" " + input.nextLine());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The first example doesn't print a leading space, the second one does.

Comment: You could replace the `IF` with a ternary operation to achieve the same effect, but it wouldn't necessarily be more readable

Comment: While the question is a basic question, it is quite well written and specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only noticeable difference is the fact that the correct answer doesn't produce an output starting with a space.

With this file:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Your code will have this output (notice space in front of "foo"):

```
 foo bar baz
```

The answer's code will have this one (no space in front of "foo"):

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your time

Comment: You're welcome, please consider marking your question as answered

Answer (score 1):

the only deference is in the first code

```
if(input.hasNext())
    System.out.print(input.nextLine());
    while (input.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(" " + input.nextLine());
    }
}
```

you will print " " -space- then the string, but in the second one, you will start from the start of the line then it will put space between the words
so

> "space" first second third

is deferent from

> first second third // without space at first

Answer (score 1):

A common problem encountered when creating a String with separators from a collection is how to avoid a surplus leading or trailing space. This is what the extra if-statement achieves. There are several other ways to solve this, below I provide two alternatives.

You could also do this:

```
// first build the output string using a StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(input.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(input.nextLine()).append(" ");      
}    
// if there was input, the StringBuilder will have an extra space at the end
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    // in that case remove the space and print the result
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Or for even more fun, a recursive solution:

```
private String read(Scanner input) {
    if (!input.hasNext()) {
        return "";
    }
    String head = input.nextLine();
    if (input.hasNext()) {            
        return head + " " + read(input);
    }
    else {
        return head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the output would start with a space. 
You could just put the space at the end and it would work fine:

```
System.out.print(input.nextLine() + " ");
```

If this still causes a problem, maybe this will work:

```
while(input.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(input.nextLine());

    if(input.hasNext())
        System.out.print(" ");
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should append a space to every line except the last one.

Comment: It isn't sufficient to use his code since the leading space makes it wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it (I can't find where I originally saw a similar usage):

```
String spacer = "";
while(input.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(spacer + input.nextLine());
    spacer = " ";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It just provides an alternative solution.

Comment: It expands on the answer already provided in the top comment by providing an alternative way to solve the separator problem

Comment: I like this solution but the ugly side of it is that you needlessly re-assign the spacer on each iteration

Comment: @AdriaanKoster the question is not asking for a solution. The question is asking for why a proposed solution is not a good answer. This answer provides an answer to some other question and not this question. While providing an alternative solution as part of an answer is certainly a nice thing, providing an alternative without answering the question is by definition not answering the question.